azure function responding with 503 or 502 error after some intervals
I have an azure function deployed which is giving this exception as follows:
[![Unable to reload azure.functions. Using default. Exception: cannot import name 'BlobSource' from 'azure.functions.decorators' (/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure/functions/decorators/init.py)][1]][1]
Along with the above exception, I am keep getting 502 or 503 error after some intervals and then it return to its ok response i.e 200.
I am deploying the azure function via the following yml file:


name: Deploy Python project to Azure Function App



on:

  push:

    branches: ["main"]



env:

  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_NAME: 'my-function-name'   

  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.'       

  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.9'                     



jobs:

  test:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest



    steps:

    - uses: actions/checkout@v4

    - name: Set up Python 3.9

      uses: actions/setup-python@v3

      with:

        python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}

    - name: Install dependencies

      run: |

        python -m pip install --upgrade pip

        pip install flake8 pytest

        if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi

    - name: Test with pytest

      run: |

        pytest --disable-warnings



  build-and-deploy:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    needs: test

    if: ${{ needs.test.result == 'success' }}

    environment: dev

    steps:

    - name: 'Checkout GitHub Action'

      uses: actions/checkout@v4



    - name: Setup Python ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }} Environment

      uses: actions/setup-python@v4

      with:

        python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}



    - name: 'Resolve Project Dependencies Using Pip'

      shell: bash

      run: |

        pushd './${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}'

        python -m pip install --upgrade pip

        pip install -r requirements.txt --target=".python_packages/lib/site-packages"

        popd



    - name: 'Run Azure Functions Action'

      uses: Azure/functions-action@v1

      id: fa

      with:

        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_NAME }}

        package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}

        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }} # Remove publish-profile to use Azure RBAC

        scm-do-build-during-deployment: true

        enable-oryx-build: true

requirements.txt


azure-functions==1.20.0

pandas==2.2.2

pydantic==2.8.2

pydantic_core==2.20.1

pytest==8.3.2

pytest-asyncio==0.23.8

requests==2.32.3


runtime version: 4
python version: 3.9
I am trying to figure out what might be causing this exception, but the exception is persistent.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
function_app.py
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from src.funcmain import *

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)

@app.route(route="register-account",methods=['POST'])
async def account_registration(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info(f'Request received from {req.url}')

    try:
        return await register_account(req=req)
    
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'Error processing request: {str(e)}')
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Internal server error :{str(e)}", status_code=500)
    
@app.route(route="contact",methods=['POST'])
async def contact(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info(f'Request received from {req.url}')

    try:
        if req.params.get('action') == 'update':
            return await update_contact(req=req)
        
        elif req.params.get('action') == 'create':
            return await register_contact(req=req)
        
        else:
            return func.HttpResponse(f"Invalid action: {req.params.get('action')}", status_code=400)
    
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'Error processing request: {str(e)}')
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Internal server error :{str(e)}", status_code=500)

@app.route(route="lead", methods=['POST'])
async def lead_operation(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info(f'Request received from {req.url}')
    try:
        if req.params.get('action') == 'update':
            return await update_lead(req)
        elif req.params.get('action') == 'create':
            return await create_lead(req)
        else:
            return func.HttpResponse(f"Invalid action: {req.params.get('action')}", status_code=400)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'Error processing request: {str(e)}')
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Internal server error: {str(e)}", status_code=500)

@app.route(route="offer", methods=['POST'])
async def offer_operation(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info(f'Request received from {req.url}')
    try:
        if req.params.get('action') == 'create':
            return await create_offer(req)
        elif req.params.get('action') == 'update':
            return await update_offer(req)
        else:
            return func.HttpResponse(f"Invalid action: {req.params.get('action')}", status_code=400)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'Error processing request: {str(e)}')
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Internal server error: {str(e)}", status_code=500)

@app.route(route="watchlist", methods=['POST'])
async def watchlist_operation(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info(f'Request received from {req.url}')
    try:
        if req.params.get('action') == 'create':
            return await add_watchlist(req)
        elif req.params.get('action') == 'update':
            return await update_watchlist(req)
        else:
            return func.HttpResponse(f"Invalid action: {req.params.get('action')}", status_code=400)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'Error processing request: {str(e)}')
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Internal server error: {str(e)}", status_code=500)

@app.route(route="ping", methods=['GET'])
async def ping(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Ping request received.')
    return func.HttpResponse("Service is Up!", status_code=200)


Please provide your function code.

@PravallikaKV updated

Just to help other who maybe facing such error where your function app is giving responses between 502 or 503 intermittently.
Follow the following steps:

Troubleshoot the issue using the diagnostic tool and solve problems through azure portal

If above didn't gave you any insights,
try looking into the runtime logs using log streaming found in left menu.

(Only for those who has subscribe to premium provision)If you're still not getting any insight or leads that may help resolve issue, check the Kudu console.Link to Console : http://<your-function-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net(check logs or memory consumption)

If you're still not getting any insights or unable to find exception,
Then it might be region specific.Your server location might be  experiencing some problem.


Try migrating your app to new region (which is bit handy) or contact support team.
I am attaching some doc for your reference:

Azure function returns 503 after 30 seconds

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1287868/how-to-solve-azure-functions-runtime-is-unreachabl

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/1567
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/8583



How did you manage to resolve the issue in your case? What is a migration to another region? Thank you.

resolved it by changing the region from Canada Central To Canada East.In which region did you have deployed your azure function?

I am in Sweden Central which is also mentioned in https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/8583. In my case, the whole app ("Web App Down") is affected. No valuable help from MS support so far.

@HenrikKobergIf no leads were found, did you check if it's a region specific problem? You could deploy a another default function and make requests to it intermittently to see if you're receiving 502 or 503 responses.

Yes, I deployed to Germany West yesterday. So far, I've encountered one instance of a 502 error, which was related to the Azure Functions specialization process. However, I haven't experienced any 503 errors yet, so I'm cautiously optimistic.

Check if you have BlobSource under .venv/Lib/Site-packages/azure/functions/decorators/init.py:
from .core import Cardinality, AccessRights
from .function_app import FunctionApp, Function, DecoratorApi, DataType, \
    AuthLevel, Blueprint, ExternalHttpFunctionApp, AsgiFunctionApp, \
    WsgiFunctionApp, FunctionRegister, TriggerApi, BindingApi, \
    SettingsApi, BlobSource
from .http import HttpMethod

__all__ = [
    'FunctionApp',
    'Function',
    'FunctionRegister',
    'DecoratorApi',
    'TriggerApi',
    'BindingApi',
    'SettingsApi',
    'Blueprint',
    'ExternalHttpFunctionApp',
    'AsgiFunctionApp',
    'WsgiFunctionApp',
    'DataType',
    'AuthLevel',
    'Cardinality',
    'AccessRights',
    'HttpMethod',
    'BlobSource'
]


I have created a Python Azure function using your modules in requirements.txt and able to deploy the function to Azure using GitHub actions.
requirements.txt:
azure-functions==1.20.0
pandas==2.2.2
pydantic==2.8.2
pydantic_core==2.20.1
pytest==8.3.2
pytest-asyncio==0.23.8
requests==2.32.3

Workflow:
name: Build and deploy Python project to Azure Function App - appname

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.' # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  PYTHON_VERSION: '3.9' # set this to the python version to use (supports 3.6, 3.7, 3.8)

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Setup Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: ${{ env.PYTHON_VERSION }}

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      # Optional: Add step to run tests here

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            release.zip
            !venv/
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-function.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Functions'
        uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
        id: deploy-to-function
        with:
          app-name: 'appname'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_8212BBXXXD0E6 }}
          scm-do-build-during-deployment: true
          enable-oryx-build: true

Deployment Status in GitHub:


Help! I am still stuck and getting the same error. The problem occur after i deploy the function app onto the cloud. please check the post i have update and shared some screenshot. After i deployed it i am also getting 502 or 503, indicates that the service is unavailable and i checked the diagnnose and problem through portal and seeing that import exception.I don't think its because of 'Cold' state, i am making request every after 5min to keep the function warm.I tried with python 3.11 and 3.9 both giving same error.

I will test with your code and update.

Appreciate it a lot. Due to this runtime error, which I believe is caused by that import issue, many of our frontend operation are down.As after some time, it alternates between giving 502 or 503 responses, and then 200, back and forth.please let me know if you require more details

Can you share your GitHub repo link if possible?

github username pls?

You can share the project repository link here.

https://github.com/rahul-08-11/BubbleCRMConnector2.0 check here

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
